# 3 column fluid layout css

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

okay im trying to make a 3 column layout but i want all of the columns to be fluid with 33% width and 50% height. I also want padding on the 3 divs for the columns. but every time i add the padding it makes the last div goto the next line.

how can i fix this??

## html

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="block" id="left">
        <h1>blah blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="middle">
        <h1>blah blah</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="right">
        <h1>blah blah</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
#nav {
    ??
}
.block {
    padding:20px;
    width:33%;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not going to work how you want it with that DOM structure. The W3 box model includes the padding and borders in the calculated width, so it adds 40px to each of those divs which puts it 120px too wide.

What you'd want to do is treat these three divs as wrappers, and then nest divs inside them which you can then assign a margin to replace the padding.

Example:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="block" id="left">
        <div>
            <h1>blah blah</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="middle">
        <div>
            <h1>blah blah</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="right">
        <div>
            <h1>blah blah</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    width:33%;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

.block>div {
    margin:20px;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Yf34X/

Comment: so all it does is the .block div's are 33% wide and then the div's inside them have 20 margin. but why does .block have to be floated left and positioned relatively? float and position always confuse me lol

Comment: They don't have to be positioned relatively. I just left that in there since it was in your original CSS. They DO have to be floated left though so they show up side-by-side. Think of floating as taking the node out of the normal flow. Position is an override of where you want the node to appear on the screen. `position:relative` means if you give it a `left:20px;`, it will be 20px to the left of where it would have normally appeared. `position:absolute;` will put it 20px to the left of the 0 coordinate of the first parent with non-static position. That's a discussion in itself ;)